# Cannot overwrite file: /var/lib/mysql/ibdata1 when using Percona xtrabackup

Tags: mysql, backup, percona

I am receiving an error when I am trying to restore from a percona backup to my local mysql server.

> Cannot overwrite file: /var/lib/mysql/ibdata1 at /usr/bin/innobackupex
>   line 2128.

```
sudo innobackupex --copy-back --force-non-empty-directories /home/fazlan/Desktop/2015-05-25_09-59-31/
```

I had also shut down the mysql service prior to executing this command using

```
sudo service mysql stop
```

How do I fix this error?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 1):

You should be restoring to a completely empty folder - you need to remove all the content (files and folders) from the target folder before doing the restore. Xtrabackup contains the entire system, not just a particular database. As always, test the restore on your test environment before attempting on production! And remember to shut down MySQL before attempting the restore or cleaning the target folder...